# Dump array of char* ASCII text to file? (ollydbg or x32dbg)

Tags: ollydbg, x64dbg

This question is similar to: [List arrays (de-reference pointers) in Ollydbg](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11889/list-arrays-de-reference-pointers-in-ollydbg?rq=1)

I have an array of pointers that point to character arrays. I followed the above link and can view the ASCII values from the dereferenced pointers, but I would like to be able to dump it to a file. The only options I see are:

1. Binary copy (these are the addresses, rather than values).
2. Copy as Table (copies all the data...not needed)

Any idea? I use both ollydbg and x32dbg so either is fine for a solution

Answer (score 1):

in ollydbg you can drag the columns to left and hide them and copy only text

[image]